# LKML mailing list RSS feed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am keen on following the activity that goes on on the official Linux Kernel Mailing list (https://lkml.org/). Looking through the website, it seems quite a tedious task to follow any thread or topic of interest.

Alternatively, I was wondering if it be possible to follow it via RSS ? I would welcome alternate suggestions on what would be the best way to keep up to date with the mailing list ?

Thanks,
vj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LKML has [one](https://lkml.org/rss.php) but [Gmane](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel) offers four different RSS feeds.

Answer (score 3):

Refer the link below for available mailing lists that are related to linux kernel.

http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html

For subscribing to LKML just send message to majordomo@vger.kernel.org with body as "subscribe linux-kernel" . The subject does not matters.

The same way you can configure for other subsystem mailing list also.

The frequency of mail transaction is more i.e around 200-400 mails/day. So it is good to configure using some mail clients.

If you do not want to have those mails in your inbox then just have a look at the urls archives provided in each mailing list.

Regards,
Yuvaraj.A